# How to get array size during compile time?

Tags: sas

I have a dataset holding parameters like thus

```
Parameters
year threshold1 threshold2
1     100       200       
2     150       300     
....
7     200       390
```

I can do

```
data output;
     set input;

     if 0 then set set parameters;

     array thresholds [2] thresholds:;

     %do year = 1 %to 7;
            year = &year.;
            set parameters point=year;

            array my_thresholds&year. [2] _temporary_;

            do i = 1 to 2;
                my_thresholds&year.[i] = thresholds[i];
            end;
     %end;
```

This would, for every observation in INPUT, threshold1 threshold2 for each year as variables and set up an array for `my_thresholds&year`. holding each.

The problem however, is if the number of thresholds is unknown. I can't do `dim(thresholds)` nor `*`.

How can I get SAS to know at compile how to set up the array?

Comment: It wouldn't be answering the question of 'How to get array size during compile time' but if you're wanting to solve the above, how about generating a group ID (eg `if year=1 then group+1`) and then transposing the dataset so that you get on observation for each group ID?

Comment: Hi Bendy, thanks for the suggestion. This would be similar to using proc contents too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge you cannot dynamically set the size of the array at the compile time.

One possibility to get this done is to use proc contents and proc sql to figure out how many threshold parameters there are in the parameters data set and then pass that information to the data step by the macro variable.

```
data parameters;
    do year=1 to 7;
        threshold1 = 1;
        threshold2 = 2;
        threshold3 = 3;
        output;
    end;
run;
proc contents data=parameters out=cont noprint;
run;
proc sql noprint;
    select count(*) into :thr_count
    from cont
    where name like "threshold%";
quit;
%put &thr_count.;
```

Comment: Using where name like "threshold%" may work. I have no idea about this function.